# Are inline function calls completed first in every browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it guaranteed that inline `onClick="asdf()"` will always **complete** before any jquery attached functionality is called? In all browsers?

Seems so,( http://jsbin.com/eribeb/1/edit ) but I haven't seen any documentation that states categorically that this is the case.

Comment: Keep in mind that `complete` here means the same thing as `start` because Javascript is single-threaded. Once a function is running it is guaranteed to finish before any other Javascript on the page runs.

Comment: @Paulpro Unless the code inside of `asdf()` is asynchronous ;-)

Comment: @Ian No, that doesn't affect it. I'll post a demo to prove it.

Comment: @Paulpro Sure it does. If you fire an AJAX request off, there's no guaranteeing the response comes back before any jQuery handlers are executed, and is very unlikely it does

Comment: @Ian That is true, but there is a request that once the response handler starts executing it will complete before any others start.

Comment: You don't even need to get that elaborate. If `asdf()` creates a timeout or an interval with significant delay, it's almost guaranteed to "complete" *after* subsequent scripts.

Comment: @Paulpro Of course. I wasn't trying to argue or start any discussion because this really doesn't pertain the OP's code, mainly because of the `;-)` in my original comment

Comment: @Paulpro this was my concern exactly. was just making the demo. Have you made yours yet? I always have trouble with ajax on jsfiddle...

Comment: @thomas I didn't know I was supposed to make a fiddle! I can if you want. But there is no reason to demonstrate it - it's true. AJAX requests are asynchronous, so there's no guarantee when the response comes back. jQuery click handlers obviously don't and shouldn't wait for any type of response like that, because they have no knowledge of that. Is there any reason you're mixing inline event handlers and jQuery event handlers? You could look into `$.Deferred`

Comment: @Ian Sorry! I got the usernames confused. Paulporo  said he was doing so. You are in no way obligated to make a fiddle. Consider yourself released! :D

Comment: @Ian When the AJAX response comes back is irrelevant. When the response comes back is not the same as when the callback is executing after the response comes back. Here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pFXyf/1/ One of the two functions starts randomly and then the other, both asynchornously. Both functions are slow and should take longer than 500 milliseconds to execute, but the other function won't start until the slow one finished

Comment: @Paulpro Your code isn't asynchronous - the `for` loops are synchronous. Sure, the `setTimeout`s queue them to be executed in order later, but the code within the "callbacks" aren't asynchronous.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, that's true. What's your point then? If `adsf()` calls something asynchronously `asdf()` still completes before the function it called asynchronously can start, whether that be an AJAX callback or a setTimeout.

Comment: @Ian I'm mixing because I use a window.bind onbeforeunload to make sure that the user is sure s/he wants to leave if the form has not been submitted. However, I don't want to have this popup when the user hits submit and the form processes off to `process.php`. So I was using `input type="submit" onClick="setAllow()">..function setAllow(){$("body").data("allow", true);}` and then the onBeforeUnload would be called, see the `data.allow` was set to true and cancel showing the confirm box.There's probably a better way. I just didn't want the jquery bound unload to fire before data var was set

Comment: @Paulpro I guess my point depended on how they defined "completes". I didn't know if they expected asynchronous callbacks (that were started in the inline handler) to wait and "complete" before any jQuery handlers. I didn't know if it was obvious to the OP. I don't know if it would help, but here's what I meant - http://jsfiddle.net/aWzRL/

Comment: @thomas In your case, that should be fine, because all of your code is synchronous. The `onclick` inline handler will execute, setting the `.data()`, then the `beforeunload` handler would be called and can check `.data()`

Comment: @Ian Thanks much! I also am enjoying watching this discussion..

Comment: @thomas And with your jsbin, the jQuery handler must wait for the inline handler to complete because the `for` loop (and all your code) is synchronous. I wish there was more to explain, but it's as simple as that - like Paulpro's first comment

Comment: @Ian. Yeah, seems like the first comment, with the qualification: "with __no__ asynchronous code" is the perfect answer.

Comment: @Paulpro Hi Paulpro. I think you should submit your first comment as an answer. It has clarified this very well for me. Thank you!